# searching through a nested-list in python

Tags: python, list, search, nested-lists

I have a nested list of tuples of  97510 values like this:

```
a = [ (1,2,3), (3,4,5), (5,4,2)]
```

every first value (index=0) is unique and I need to find other index=0 items that have the same index=1 items 
In the example , I need to find the second and third tuples where the the second item '4' is common .

How do I do it ?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to find all matches:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for inner in a:
...     d[inner[1]].append(inner)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {2: [(1, 2, 3)], 4: [(3, 4, 5), (5, 4, 2)]})
>>> d[4]
[(3, 4, 5), (5, 4, 2)]
```

If you want to pick out all matches for a particular second value:

```
>>> filter(lambda inner: inner[1] == 4, a)
[(3, 4, 5), (5, 4, 2)]
```

**Edit**: As pointed out in the comments, a list comprehension is preferable as it is more efficient for such work:

```
>>> [inner for inner in a if inner[1] == 4]
[(3, 4, 5), (5, 4, 2)]
```

Using `timeit` shows the list comprehension is about 2.5 times faster (on my machine anyway):

```
>>> timeit.timeit('[inner for inner in a if inner[1] == 4]', 'a=[(1,2,3), (3,4,5), (5, 4, 2)]')
2.5041549205780029
>>> timeit.timeit('filter(lambda inner: inner[1] == 4, a)', 'a=[(1,2,3), (3,4,5), (5, 4, 2)]')
6.328679084777832
```

Comment: I would generally prefer a list comprehension over `filter` with a lambda - `[item for item from a if item[1] == 4]`. It is, in my opinion, better to read.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y - yeah, I usually would too. Not sure why I used filter in this answer. I've updated it with some timing examples - as well as nicer to read, its quicker.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it:

```
>>> result = defaultdict(list)
>>> for item in a:
>>>     result[item[1]].append(item)
>>> result
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {2: [(1, 2, 3)], 4: [(3, 4, 5), (5, 4, 2)]})
```

This will result in a dictionary of lists where all items with the same second value are in one list, with that value as the key.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can also use [groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [ (1,2,3), (3,4,5), (5,4,2)]
res = groupby(sorted(data), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Edited as per comment

Played around with the problem and found one more solution - however not the best one, but:

```
inputVals = [(1,2,3), (3,4,5), (5,4,2), (2,2,3), (7,3,1)]
for val in set(x[1] for x in inputVals):   
    print val, list(set(sval for sval in inputVals if sval[1] == val))
```

Comment: Sure, thank you, My answer intended to simply notify OP that he also has one more option.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

a = [ (1,2,3), (3,4,5), (5,4,2)]
b = groupby(sorted(a), itemgetter(1))
for val, group in b:
    print val, list(group)
# 2 [(1, 2, 3)]
# 4 [(3, 4, 5), (5, 4, 2)]
```

Comment: Nice. I always forget about itertools, its something I need to play with more.

Comment: This sorts the list first and then iterates over it. Giving a complexity of O(n log n) plus an additional pass over the list. This is not efficient.